# C++ - некорректное определение отдельного символа в строке

Tags: c++, linux, unicode, char

Всем привет!
Проблема заключается в следующем - имеются Linux с Code:Blocks IDE и g++ в качестве компилятора, программный код C++, а так же символьная строка (`string` либо `char []`), которой присваивается текст в кириллических символах. При выводе всей строки, выводимый текст в консоли отображается нормально. Но если обращаться к любому отдельному элементу строки, то вместо символа выводится вопросительный знак на фоне ромба и я так понимаю, что сама программа не может определить - какой это символ, так как условный оператор на него не реагирует. Кодировка естественно - Unicode (UTF-8).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string word = "Слово";
  cout << word; //нормально выводится "Слово"
  cout << word [0]; //выводится '?'
  if (word [0] == "С") cout << word [0]; //оператор if считает, что false
  return 0;
}
```

**UPD:** в общем и целом мне не нужна была большая программа, поэтому я просто создал отдельную строку, к которой присваивается необходимая пара элементов проверяемой строки содержащая один нужный символ (`[0], [1]; [2], [3]` и тд). Полученную строку вполне удаётся использовать в условных операторах:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 string word = "Слово", letter;
 letter += word [0];
 letter += word [1];
 if (letter == "С") cout << letter;//true, выводится "С"
 return 0;
}
```

Разумеется, это выглядит топорно, но на мой взгляд это самый простой способ в контексте, скажем например, университетской лабораторной работы.
**Спасибо всем за помощь и полезную информацию (=**

Comment: вероятно, минимальный пример того, что вы делаете, совсем не помешат. дополнить вопрос можно, нажав [edit] под текстом вопроса.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Кодировка UTF-8 это многобайтовая кодировка, один символ может кодироваться несколькими байтами.

В частности русские буквы кодируются двумя байтами, например 'ы' кодируется как "\xd1\x8b".

Когда Вы пытаетесь напечатать один байт закодированной буквы, например "\xd1" или "\x8b", то выводится как знак вопроса, потому что это не валидная UTF-8 строка.

Comment: Хорошо, в таком случае, как можно реализовать работу с отдельными символами, если они русские и находятся в кодировке UTF-8?

Comment: @TheCat, [например](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10846953/4827341).

Comment: @TheCat, или использовать iconv либо ICU (хотя по ссылке есть упоминания оного)

Answer (score 3):

В качестве альтернативного решения, если вам нужна работа с отдельными символами, и вы уверены, что вам не придётся работать с экзотикой наподобие символов Unicode, лежащих за главной плоскостью, попробуйте перевести вашу программу на широкие строки:

```
wstring word = L"Слово";
wcout << word;
wcout << word[0];
if (word[0] == L'С') wcout << word[0];
```

Это повысит расход памяти, но избавит вас от великого и ужасного ICU. Тем не менее, это оставляет вас наедине с возможной диакритикой (акценты наподобие точек и крючочков у `ü` или там `ç` всё равно занимают отдельный `wchar_t`).

В C++ нет строк, смиритесь. Всё вручную.

---

Да, и убедитесь, что ваша консоль работает в нужном режиме (это системно-зависимая вещь).

Comment: К сожалению, при использовании широких строк, перестали выводиться и строки полностью. Но тут выводятся уже на вопросики на фоне ромбовидных фигур, а обычные вопросительные знаки.
А  что вы имеете в виду под нужным режимом консоли?

Comment: @TheCat: А `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");` в начале программы на помогает?

Comment: 'setlocale' не  помогает

Comment: @TheCat: А пример отсюда тоже не работает: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15455884/276994?

Comment: @TheCat: И этот: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18675957/276994?

Answer (score 1):

В общем и целом, мне не нужна была большая программа, поэтому я просто создал отдельную строку, к которой присваивается необходимая пара элементов проверяемой строки содержащая один нужный символ ([0], [1]; [2], [3] и тд). Полученную строку вполне удаётся использовать в условных операторах:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
 string word = "Слово", letter;
 letter += word [0];
 letter += word [1];
 if (letter == "С") cout << letter;//true, выводится "С"
 return 0;
}
```

Разумеется, это выглядит топорно, но на мой взгляд это самый простой способ в контексте, скажем например, университетской лабораторной работы.
**Спасибо всем за помощь и полезную информацию (=**